# SQL extract - displaying data in excel

Tags: excel, pivot, reporting

I am trying to create a report from a SQL data extract but my current layout is just a list like this:

[image]

I would ideally like to have the report show like this:

[image]

as it would be easier to filter and analyse:

I have tried using a Pivot table to view the data but can't seem to make it work as you can only add values to the 'value' section of the pivot table unless there's something I have missed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you're trying to pivot the SQL extract, I would guess that pivot tables are not a bad choice.  But, you could also get the output you want by doing a pivot query in Excel.

Comment: Thanks, I used the Query Editor in Excel, it's a pretty useful tool!